# Xcode 9: %appName% does not have an architecture that %deviceName% can execute

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, xcode9

I've encountered such errors in Xcode 9 that are listed below:

```
%appName% does not have an architecture that %deviceName% can execute.
```

[image: example of such wtf]

```
Target 'Pods-%appName%' of project 'Pods' was rejected as an implicit dependency for 'Pods_%appName%.framework' because its architectures 'armv7' didn't contain all required architectures 'arm64'
```

[image: example of such wtf]

Despite this, I have the right project settings:

1. `Valid Arhitectures` are set to `arm64 armv7 armv7s`
2. `Build Active Architecture Only` is enabled in `Debug` mode only.

For a long time I could not understand the reason. I walked the wrong way, stepping on the rake. I learned all the questions about Xcode/Cocoapods at SO, but did not get an answer.

If you encounter such errors, the solution is indicated below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read `architecture` as `target`, change the `target` to the appropriate one, as on the device.